# Get a list of users who have full control to a sub site using j query or rest api in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, office365api

Is there a way you can have a list of users who have full control to a web. 
There is a function called owner which gives the owner of current site collection but is there anything similar for a sub site or web.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function that gives you all the permission for the user when you provide a username and web URL

```
  function getUserRoles(webUrl,accountName)
  {
   return getUserEffectivePermissions(webUrl,accountName).then(function(data){
    var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data);
    var permLevels = [];
    for(var permLevelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
        if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(permLevelName)) {
           var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(permLevelName);
           if(permissions.has(permLevel)){
              permLevels.push(permLevelName);
            }
        }     
    }
    return permLevels;
  });   
}
```

use this rest api to get all users and filter the login name

**_api/web/siteusers**

to get the subsite use this

**/_api/web/webinfos**